# Assert Equal two list of objects UnitTesting c#

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm currently doing some unit testing of a copy function and I need to compare the elements of the objects between the old list, and the newly copied list.
It works fine, but I was wondering if I can do it in a way that doesn't involve a for loop.
Here is my object:

```
new NaturePointObject
            {
                SId = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                Category = NaturePointCategory.Category1,
                CreatorType = CreatorTypeEnum.1,
                NaturR = NaturR.Bn,
                Description = "Test",
                Kumulation = Kumulation.EnEjendom,
                Id = 1
            }
```

My old list contains "NaturePointObject" and is called naturPointList, and it will be copied to a list called newNaturePointList.
Here is how I Assert to know if it copied succesfully:

```
Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList.Count,newNaturePointList.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < newNatureList.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].Category, newNaturePointList[i].Category);
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].Description, newNaturePointList[i].Description);
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].Kumulation, newNaturePointList[i].Kumulation);
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].Name, newNaturePointList[i].Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].CreatorType, newNaturePointList[i].CreatorType);
            Assert.AreEqual(naturPointList[i].NaturR, newNaturePointList[i].NaturR);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(naturPointList[i].SId, newNaturePointList[i].SId);
        }
```

As you can see not all elements of the object must be equal. And I don't care about the "Id" of the object.

Is there a shorter way to do this, than run a for loop?

Comment: Shorter in which way? You can avoid the loop stuf with a LinQ query, but it will still create a loop under the hood.

Comment: Since you are literally doing an object compare(ignoring ID) you can take a look at this https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual it is available as nuget package.

Comment: @fharreau Just shorter to look at. It doesn't matter that it's the same under the hood.

Comment: @Aravind Will take a look at it

Comment: You stated that you don't care about the Id of the object, yet you have a specific assertion to ensure that they are not equal. It seems like you **do** care...

Comment: How complex is this method that copies items from one list to another? Is it generic? If so, could you test with a simpler object?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use `CollectionAssert`:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(naturPointList, newNaturePointList, NaturePointObject.CategoryCreatorTypeComparer);
```

The only thing you need to take in mind is that you need to implement `IComparer`, to use in the `Assert` method:

```
public class NaturePointObject
{
    private static readonly Comparer<NaturePointObject> CategoryCreatorTypeComparerInstance = new CategoryCreatorTypeRelationalComparer();

    private sealed class CategoryCreatorTypeRelationalComparer : Comparer<NaturePointObject>
    {
        public override int Compare(NaturePointObject x, NaturePointObject y)
        {
            // compare fields which makes sense
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return 0;
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return 1;
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, x)) return -1;
            var categoryComparison = string.Compare(x.Category, y.Category, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (categoryComparison != 0) return categoryComparison;
            return string.Compare(x.CreatorType, y.CreatorType, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }
    }

    public static Comparer<NaturePointObject> CategoryCreatorTypeComparer
    {
        get
        {
            return CategoryCreatorTypeComparerInstance;
        }
    }

    public int SId { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public string CreatorType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Assert.IsTrue(naturPointList.SequenceEqual(newNaturePointList));
```

If you want to ignore the Id, you can create other classes (without Ids).

Later edit: you could overwrite the Equals method and ignore the Id.